# Maven - how to extract/download dependencies from a remote pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, remote-server

I am putting together a `pom.xml` for a java project.  This java project has some java code that depends on a number of other libraries that exist in a private remote repository.

In my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-id</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>9.1.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the artifact is a `pom`.  This POM contains references to all the dependencies for the artifact ID `my-id`.

The issue I'm facing is this:

1. If I change the `<type>` to `jar`, it doesn't work because the actual file is not a single jar, it is a POM file that references all of the dependencies.
2. The remote POM is downloaded, but maven doesn't download and install all of the dependent `.jar` libraries referenced in the remote POM.

How can I achieve the end goal of having maven grab the latest POM file from the remote repo and subsequently download as dependencies all of the jars listed in this remote `pom.xml`?  Is this even possible?

Comment: A pom project doesn't have dependencies.  Typically it is used for parent-level modules that supply dependencyManagement for the rest of the modules in the project.  If you use a <scope>import</scope> you will pull in all of the properties and dependency management data to use within your project.  This does not add physical dependencies.

Comment: The <scope>import</scope> doesn't apply to a dependency, so this doesn't work.

Comment: It should work. Add a dependency to your pom with `<type>pom</type>` and `<scope>import</scope>`. This should pull the dependencies declared in the POM.

Comment: I got the following when I used <scope>import</scope>:  [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycom::1.1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for com.mycom:myId:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 44, column 24

Comment: What is your Maven version? You shouldn't have that (did you have `<type>pom</type>` also?)

Comment: You put imported poms into the dependencyManagement section.  Poms are NOT dependencies.  Your time might be better spent reading the maven documentation.  You're essentially trying to have a POM that lists a collection of dependencies that you want to use in many places.  This is not how maven was intended to work.  Look up the concept of a Bill of Materials (BOM) which is what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: @Tunaki I'm using maven for mac os version 3.3.3, mac os x 10.11.1